# The underlying table for model 'Order' does not exist. Error code: P1014 (Prisma)

Tags: nestjs, prisma, prisma2

I have such problem as below

```
$ prisma migrate dev --name "ok"
    
Error: P3006
    
Migration `2021080415559_order_linking` failed to apply clearnly to the shadow database.
Error code: P1014
Error:
The underlying table for model 'Order' does not exist.
```

**How to fix it?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution:

It seems that this may be due to the migration file in the prisma folder.
I decided to delete the Migration Files and the whole folder with it. I restarted the application, it got a new file and it worked.

```
*delete the migrations folder*

$ prisma generate

$ prisma migrate dev --name "ok"

*it works*
```

Comment: be aware, deleting all migration files could negatively impact on your further development

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your migrations were corrupted somehow. There was probably changes to your database that was not recorded in the migration history.

You could try one of these:

- If you're okay with losing the data in the database, try resetting the database with `prisma migrate reset`. [More info](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/command-reference#migrate-reset)
- Try running introspection to capture any changes to the database with `prisma introspect` before applying a new migration. [More info](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/introspection)