# Error validating: You defined the enum but the current connector does not support enums

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, prisma

This is React JS project in which I'm transferring DB from postgres to sqlite, in `schema.prisma` file I'm writing enum for some tables and it gives me an error that **Error validating: You defined the enum but the current connector does not support enums.**
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just follow these steps indicates in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68700352/the-underlying-table-for-model-order-does-not-exist-error-code-p1014-prisma) then add all the migration files into migration folder and ran `yarn db-migrate` problem resolved, hope it'll help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Prisma seems to have removed their shim for enums in sqlite back in 2020. See [issue Prisma issue #1906](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/1906) for details.

You might find this answer helpful in seeking out an alternative to using enums:

- [How to create ENUM type in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299267/how-to-create-enum-type-in-sqlite)